# Error resolving version for plugin 'maven-dependency-plugin:2.8'

Tags: maven, nexus

I tried to install a prototyp from internet and need to execute mvn maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy. It is not working because of error reloving version. I have a right version on local also on repository into my server. my mvn is bundled to nexus on my server.

What is wrong?

Error-message:

```
mvn -e maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.131s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 24 11:15:01 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/149M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'maven-dependency-plugin:2.8' from the repositories [local (/home/argonist/.m2/repository), nexus (http://10.8.1.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolutionException: Error resolving version for plugin 'maven-dependency-plugin:2.8' from the repositories [local (/home/argonist/.m2/repository), nexus (http://10.8.1.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.selectVersion(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:237)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolveFromRepository(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.resolvePluginVersion(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:277)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
```

Repository on local:

```
ll /home/argonist/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/
insgesamt 188
drwxrwxr-x 2 argonist argonist   4096 Jul 24 10:24 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 argonist argonist   4096 Jul 24 10:23 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 argonist argonist    107 Jul 24 11:14 m2e-lastUpdated.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 argonist argonist 153185 Jul 24 10:23 maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 argonist argonist     40 Jul 24 10:23 maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.jar.sha1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 argonist argonist  11454 Jul 24 10:23 maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
-rw-rw-r-- 1 argonist argonist     40 Jul 24 10:23 maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom.sha1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 argonist argonist    205 Jul 24 10:23 _maven.repositories
```

**Update**

```
mvn -e org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.416s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 24 17:15:39 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/149M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Either artifact or artifactItems is required -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Either artifact or artifactItems is required 
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Either artifact or artifactItems is required 
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.verifyRequirements(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.CopyMojo.doExecute(CopyMojo.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**Update**

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.glassfish.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee7-jms-websocket-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>javaee7-jms-websocket-example</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha13</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this .. you should give the fully qualified name i.e groupId:artifactId:version

```
mvn -e org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy
```

for more reference see the maven central repo .

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|maven-dependency-plugin

Comment: If you see the logs for the first time it was not able to find the plugin itself because groupId was missing now when second time you executed it you are not mentioning anything about artifact which you want to copy.


Please go through this link.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

Comment: I checked it with my pom.xml. It is the same. I dont understand why can it not find the plugin. I can find it in nexus. Also it is in the public group.

Comment: Please remove the configuration tag from inside the execution tag

and then try to run again .


Thanks

Comment: it is not working. :( error message from eclipse: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (execution: default, phase: validate)

Comment: ru running thru eclipse or command prompt ???
its working just now i tested it on command prompt by executing the same command.

Comment: command prompt. that means nexus is not good. maybe i should use without my own nexus. then i try with my nexus later. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Prior to search in your local repository, maven searchs for this plugin in your nexus artifact repository, that lives at:

```
http://10.8.1.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public
```

Exception:

```
Plugin not found in any plugin repository
```

But not found. Put the artifact in Nexus and maven will download it to your local repository.

Comment: But I found it in the repository. Here: /nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.jar

Comment: is this repository set as public? I think you have to put the repository in the public group to be accessible

Comment: It is public as the other libs and also into the public group. I can access that lib with firefox without loggin. it is strange

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for the `maven-failsafe-plugin`. I specified a version for the plugin (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926317/5108777)).