# AEM WKND Apache Maven Build Failure

Tags: java, git, eclipse, maven, aem

I'm setting up the "Getting Started with AEM Sites - WKND Tutorial" and have installed Adobe Experience Manager 6.5, Java 15.0.1, Maven 3.6.3, Node.js v14.15.4, npm 6.14.4, and Eclipse on my Windows 10 PC, but keep getting a BUILD FAILURE when I execute one of the first steps, which is this:

Verify that the adobe-public profile is active by running the following command:

`mvn help:effective-settings`

When I run the above, I get this:

```
$ mvn help:effective-settings
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from adobe-public-releases: https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to adobe-public-releases (https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Transfer failed for https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.768 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-30T10:38:31-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\bg8157\.m2\repository), adobe-public-releases (https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
```

In the ERROR statements, I saw this...

"Plugin not found in any plugin repository"

...researched it, and found this:

[Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin' from the repositories ,Plugin not found in any plugin repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002459/error-resolving-version-for-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-jar-plugin-f), where there's a mention to edit the pom.xml file, but I have 15 pom.xml files on my PC and don't want to mess anything else up trying to fix this. Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: this is the problem ->  `[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to adobe-public-releases (https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Transfer failed for https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml`, if you are in a corp network, fix maven proxy settings.

Comment: Wow. I disconnected from my corp VPN and it worked. Thanks!